# Unable to load image from asset URL

Tags: iphone, alassetslibrary

I have a class that stores information about the assets on the phone (images, videos).

My class has the `ResourceURLString` defined as such

```
@property NSURL *ResourceURL;
```

I am setting the property while looping trough the `assets` on the phone as such

```
Item.ResourceURLString = [[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs] objectForKey:[[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyRepresentations] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

When the user clicks on an image I want to load the image.

The code that I have is this

```
NSData *imageUrl = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[CurrentItem.ResourceURL absoluteString]]];    

Img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageUrl];
```

But the Image is always nil
I have verified that the ResourceURL property contains the URL
assets: `library://asset/asset.JPG?id=82690321-91C1-4650-8348-F3FD93D14613&ext=JPG`

Comment: Real problem aside, you're converting a `NSURL` into `NSString` form and back again, which is completely pointless

Answer (score 14):

You can't load images in this way.

You need to use `ALAssetsLibrary` class for this.

Add assetslibrary framework to your project and add header files.

Use the below code for loading image:

```
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
    if (iref) {
        UIImage *largeimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
        yourImageView.image = largeImage;
    }
};

ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
{
    NSLog(@"Can't get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
};

NSURL *asseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:yourURL];
ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:asseturl 
                   resultBlock:resultblock
                  failureBlock:failureblock];
```

Comment: I have followed you code and What If I want to add Image URL to this line of code [_pinterest createPinWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"??"]; What URLString Should I right there to get an Image in pinterest?

Comment: @MayurCM: `yourURL` represents the asset url, it'll look something like: `library://asset/asset.JPG?id=82690321-91C1-4650-8348-F3FD93D14613&ext=JPG`. You can't use web url here. Asset library is used to load the image from photolibrary not from the web or bundle.

Comment: But When I pass assetsLibrary then also I'm unable to pin image on pinterest.

Comment: `assetForURL` is an asynchronous method. you could not get the result immediately.

Answer (score 8):

Since **iOS 8** you can use the  [Photos Framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos) here is how to do it in **Swift 3**

```
import Photos // use the Photos Framework

// declare your asset url
let assetUrl = URL(string: "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=9F983DBA-EC35-42B8-8773-B597CF782EDD&ext=JPG")!

// retrieve the list of matching results for your asset url
let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [assetUrl], options: nil)


if let photo = fetchResult.firstObject {

    // retrieve the image for the first result
    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: photo, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil) {
        image, info in

        let myImage = image //here is the image
    }
}
```

Use **PHImageManagerMaximumSize** if you want to retrieve the original size of the picture. But if you want to retrieve a smaller or specific size you can replace **PHImageManagerMaximumSize** by `CGSize(width:150, height:150)`

Answer (score 6):

As of iOS 9.0 `ALAssetsLibrary`is deprecated. Since iOS 8.0, this works with the PHPhotoLibrary. This is a small UIImage extension, Swift 2X.
This uses a fixed image size.

```swift
import Photos

extension UIImageView {

    func imageFromAssetURL(assetURL: NSURL) {

        let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([assetURL], options: nil)

        guard let result = asset.firstObject where result is PHAsset else {
           return
        }

        let imageManager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()

        imageManager.requestImageForAsset(result as! PHAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFill, options: nil) { (image, dict) -> Void in
            if let image = image {
                self.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Getting the imageReferenceURL from the UIImagePickerController delegate:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL
}
```

Setting the image

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.imageFromAssetURL(imageURL)
```

There might be effects I haven't encountered yet, a classic would be UITableViewCell or thread problems. I'll keep this updated, also appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5

`fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs)` will be removed in a future release. Hence we using `fetchAssets` to get image from asset local identifier

```swift
extension UIImageView {
func imageFromLocalIdentifier(localIdentifier: String, targetSize: CGSize) {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        // sort by date desending
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        // fetch photo with localIdentifier
        let results = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [localIdentifier], options: fetchOptions)
        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        results.enumerateObjects { (thisAsset, _, _) in
            manager.requestImage(for: thisAsset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: nil, resultHandler: {(image, _) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in
                    self?.image = image
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

```
let image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOf: imageURL as URL)! as Data)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ALAsset *asset = "asset array index"
[tileView.tileImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]]];
```