# Load UIImage from photos album by url

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

For the first time I'm trying to save and load a photo, taken by the camera or chosen from the photo gallery. I managed to save pictures, taken by the camera, in the photos album and getting the url of it. I hope the last part is correct. Here is the corresponding code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    self.selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    if (self.userCreatedPhoto == TRUE) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage],nil,nil,nil);
    }

    self.imageURL = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];

    [self.imageView setImage:self.selectedImage];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The photo url gets saved, together with other data, as a NSData object in core data.

```
article.imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.imageURL];
```

Assuming that everything up there is correct, I try to show the saved pictures in a UICollectionView. At this point I fail to load the picture. The following code worked in an earlier development stage of my app where I was saving the whole picture to a NSData in core data and not saving it in the album. Please correct me if I'm wrong and there is a better way, but I thought it would be better this way. So here is the code in the cellForIteamAtIndexPath UICollectionView:

```
cell.image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[[_allArticles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] imageData]];
```

Using this code, no picture appears at all when using the photo album. I hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please check [Unable to load image from asset URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496910/unable-to-load-image-from-asset-url)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't find that.

Comment: It's ok, please double check in SO before you post a question :) In most case the question will be already present in SO

Comment: Yeah that was my thought as well but I've searched for almost 3 hours and still didn't find it :)