# How to load image from local path in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have path of the Image like "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1F14BFD6-9E77-4DD8-A790-D1A2F234E005&ext=JPG"

I would like to create new image or create image stream from above path.

How can we create Image from local path? I have tried below code but imageStream returns null

```
var imageStream = NSData.FromUrl(new NSUrl(url));
UIImage image = UIImage.LoadFromData(imageStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static UIImage FromUrl (string uri)
{
    using (var url = new NSUrl (uri))
    using (var data = NSData.FromUrl (url))
        return UIImage.LoadFromData (data);
}
```

Also, if you have to get it from Assets follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21494613/2974780).