# How show the Path inside a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I use this command to get the path of an image that I'm saving in iOS library:

```
UIImage *viewImage = YOUR UIIMAGE  // --- mine was made from drawing context
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];  
// Request to save the image to camera roll  
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[viewImage CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[viewImage imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){  
    if (error) {  
        NSLog(@"error");  
    } else {  
            NSLog(@"url %@", assetURL);  
    }  
}];
```

I get this code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457904/iphone-how-do-i-get-the-file-path-of-an-image-saved-with-uiimagewritetosavedpho) topic:

I realize some test and the console log returns me a messange:

> ```
> url assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=408C8B00-23DC-4DCF-9837-C294720940F9&ext=JPG
> ```

Now I want to pick this Path and put inside a UIImageView, I try this:

```
imageView.image = @"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=408C8B00-23DC-4DCF-9837-C294720940F9&ext=JPG";
```

But doesn't work, someone can help me?

Comment: You probably want to refer to UIImage rather than UIImageView. ImageViews are basically views with an image property

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496910/unable-to-load-image-from-asset-url.  You need to use the URL to get the `ALAsset` and then pull the image of interest from its properties.

Answer (score -1):

You're going to need to use `imageNamed:` or `imageWithContentsOfFile:` however, with the Asset Library I don't think you can access it directly.

Here is a stack overflow answer that shows how to access the asset url and extract the image from the library

[Unable to load image from asset URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496910/unable-to-load-image-from-asset-url)

Comment: You can't use either of these methods to get an image from Asset Library.  Instead of directly referencing another answer as effectively your entire answer, mark the question as a duplicate.