# Fetch a saved image and display

Tags: ios, image, path

I am developing an App in which I have stored  images through imagePicker. now i want to display same images in my collectionView. I got response as a path

```
path=assets/image/155/155_557b1259b8a51.jpg
```

when i add http://xyz.com.assets/image/155/155_557b1259b8a51.jpg then it shows error.
How can i get the images through this path.Please Help me out.

Comment: where are you storing image?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: How do I get the file path of an image saved with UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457904/iphone-how-do-i-get-the-file-path-of-an-image-saved-with-uiimagewritetosavedpho)

Comment: @M Swapnil hi , i hope this like help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496910/unable-to-load-image-from-asset-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know the image path or name then you may implement something like this.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50.0, 50.0)];
cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50.0, 50.0)];

    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"your photo name here" ofType:@"png"]]];//if Path is from main bundle
//else
// documentDirectory URL as
NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
}

[cell setBackgroundView:imageView];
NSLog(@"%@",cell);
NSLog(@"Index Path = %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
return cell;
}
```

you also need to set `delegate and datasource` of `UICollectionView` as

```
[yourCollectionViewObject setDelegate:self];// if you need to use didselect or like...
[yourCollectionViewObject setDataSource:self];
```

and another required datasource method for returning count...

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return count;
}
```

Comment: the name by which you saved the image in document directory